# Export[..., "tsv"] drops minus signs from Dataset [horrific bug?]

Tags: bugs, export, dataset

Toy example:

First, create a `Dataset`:

```
data = Dataset[{<|"x" ->  1, "y" -> -2|>,
                <|"x" -> -3, "y" ->  4|>}]
```

> [image: Mathematica graphics]

Next, export it as a TSV file:

```
Export["/tmp/data.tsv", data, "tsv"];
```

Finally, check output from the Unix command-line:

```
% cat /tmp/data.tsv
```

> ```
>  x    y
>  1    2
>  3    4
> ```

Note that the minus signs are missing from the output!

---

I'm using Version 11.1.0.0 for Linux (64-bit).

---

**NB:** I have not looked into this problem systematically.  In particular, I have not looked at other formats, other conditions that may lead to loss of data, other versions of Mathematica, other OSs, etc.

Comment: Confirmed this behavior also  on Mac OS (`$Version=11.0.1 for Mac OS X x86 (64-bit) (September 21, 2016)` )

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, this looks like a bug, it also happens on Windows 11.1.1 and Linux 11.1.1, however, until this is fixed in the next version (which is certainly will be, right WRI?), you can do this simple workaround:

```
ExportString[#, "TSV"] &@
Map[Values]@
Normal@Dataset[{<|"x" -> 1, "y" -> -2|>, <|"x" -> -3, "y" -> 4|>}]
```

Comment: This is already fixed in our internal development version and will be in the next release.